# Timer on windows service doesn't work on the server

Tags: c#, .net, windows, timer

I have a windows service that uses a timer. The timer works every some seconds and check for some changes in the database and do then if any changes, the windows service does do actions.

I did everything, with a heavy testing on my machine, on my machine, the windows service is working perfectly.

When I deployed on the server, the windows service checks for database changes just when i `start` the windows service, but it doesn't keep itself checking for any changes in the database. I don't know the problem and I have been stick here for three days in a row, I checked everything.

On my machine I deploy using framework 32 and on the server I also deploy using framework 32.

I also tried to deploy on the server using framework 64, but still the same problem.

I did a log for any failure and there is no error logs at all.

Could you give me any hint about where the problem could be raising?

I run the windows service with the timer like this:

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer;

public ServiceStatus()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer(30000);  // 30000 milliseconds = 30 seconds
        this.timer.AutoReset = true;
        this.timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer_Elapsed);
        this.timer.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        this.EventLog.WriteEntry("ERROR ERROR ERROR="+ee.Message);
    }
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    this.timer.Stop();
    this.timer = null;
}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    new StatusHandler().check();
}
```

It has been three days and I am not able to solve, please any hint is appreciated.

Comment: In the code you have posted you are not handling any errors in your call to `StatusHandler().check();`. So if an exception is thrown it will exit the service and show the behavior you are describing. Unless of course your `check` method does have error handling, maybe show the code to that?

Comment: @Belogix okay I will upload more code, just a minute please

Comment: @Belogix i just added try and catch and deployed again, i will update you if any error happened in the log

Comment: @Belogix oh oh oh I started to get errors in the log `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: That'll be the issue then! :-) Hopefully now you can track down the bug and fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because the try / catch block in `OnStart` will only handle exceptions thrown in the code setting up the event. It will not catch any exceptions when the event itself runs.

If an exception is thrown in your `StatusHandler().check()` method the service will exit and nothing will be logged.

Therefore you need to add try / catch to your `StatusHandler().check()` method so that you can trap any exceptions, log them and handle them appropriately.